# "unknown register alias" errors when building VLC for Android on a Mac

Tags: android, macos, libvlc

I'm trying to build VLC for Android on a Mac, but I get these errors:

```
INSTALL libavformat/libavformat.a
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:146: Error: unknown register alias 'GP'
clang38: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:446: Error: unknown register alias 'POUT'
{standard input}:448: Error: unknown register alias 'PIN'
{standard input}:450: Error: unknown register alias 'PCOEF'
```

Somebody told me that I should modify `.configure` to disable asm. How would I do that? And wouldn't that ruin the performance of VLC?

Answer (score 1):

How to disable the asm:
1. vi vlc/contrib/src/ffmpeg/rules.mak
2. add option "disable-asm"

FYI

```
19 FFMPEGCONF = \
  20     --cc="$(CC)" \
  21     --pkg-config="$(PKG_CONFIG)" \
  22     --disable-doc \
  23     --disable-asm \
  24     --disable-encoder=vorbis \
  25     --disable-decoder=opus \
  26     --enable-libgsm \
  27     --enable-libopenjpeg \
  28     --disable-debug \
  29     --disable-avdevice \
  30     --disable-devices \
  31     --disable-avfilter \
  32     --disable-filters \
  33     --disable-protocol=concat \
  34     --disable-bsfs \
  35     --disable-bzlib \
  36     --disable-avresample
  37 
  38 ifdef USE_FFMPEG
  39 FFMPEGCONF += \
  40     --disable-swresample \
  41     --disable-iconv \
  42     --disable-avisynth \
  43     --disable-nvenc
  44 ifdef HAVE_DARWIN_OS
  45 FFMPEGCONF += \
 <rib/src/ffmpeg/rules.mak   CWD: ~/workspace/vlc-android   Line: 23
"vlc/contrib/src/ffmpeg/rules.mak" 239L, 4911C
```